# PHP array with select menu..

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array. I need the array to do the text on the left. But it is doing what is in the select box. Here is code. When I choose "This is One" when I echo it out I want it to be "one" but it is doing "This is One"...

```
array( "name" => __('Choose Slider Transition','Slider'),
"desc" => __('Choose The Slider Transition for Slide 1.'),
"id" => $shortname."_1_transition",
"type" => "select",
"options" => array(
    'none' => 'none',
    'one' => 'This is One',
    'two' => 'This is Two',
    'three' => 'This is Three'),
    "std" => "fade"),
```

Comment: How are you creating your drop down? provide html

Comment: This is not a drop down. This is PHP calling script from a theme options panel.

Comment: Are you using any framework or CMS?

Comment: This is for WordPress..I have an option panel. When I select it then the code comes out on page how I do not want.. Here is code I am using to call it <?php // Value from Dropdown $sample_dropdown = get_option('shortname_1_transition); echo $sample_dropdown; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Perhaps I'm not misunderstanding):

```
<select name="select" id="clselect">
<option value="None">None</option>
<option value="One">This is One</option>
<option value="Two">This is Two</option>
<option value="Three">This is Three</option>
</select>

<?php
$getdata=substr($_POST['clselect']),0,-4)
echo $getdata;
?>
```

Comment: <?php
// Value from Dropdown
$sample_dropdown = get_option('shortname_sample_dropdown');
echo $sample_dropdown;
?>

Comment: what actually you want. Sorry, I don't understand .. :p